Matlab Inexplicably turning character vector into an N*N array
as part of a course on Information Security I am implementing simple forms of encryption, in this case the shift cipher. I created a simple function to perform the encryption on plaintext and return the ciphertext.
function ciphertext = encrypt(plaintext, k)

%first, call the "double" function on the plaintext
%this converts it to numbers for ASCII usage
%we add k to all these numbers

asciivec = double(plaintext);

for i = 1:length(asciivec)
    if (asciivec(i) + k) > 90
        diff = (asciivec(i) + k) - 90;
        adjustedvec(i) = 64 + diff;
    else
        adjustedvec(i) = asciivec(i) + k;
    end
end

%vector is adjusted, convert back to characters
ciphertext = char(adjustedvec);

return

When I call this is main, the output is all wrong. If I feed it a character vector such as 'testing', it should return a vector in the format of 'xxxxxxx' adjusted by the proper k according to the cipher, however the actual result ends up being as such:
ciphertext =
 7x7 char array

'x      '
'x      '
'x      '
'x      '
'x      '
'x      '
'x      '
This does not occur when I run the function as a standalone script, only when I run it as a function.
I turned the function into a standalone program and hardcoded the inputs, with both being in the same format as in main. When I did this, the function worked properly and the result of ciphertext was a char vector as expected. So why does this work alone and not in main?
Main below
clc

plaintext = 'SSOEATBENEDUMHALLOHARASTREET';
k = 3;

secrets = encrypt(plaintext, k);


the ciphertext part got a little messed up, but to be clear the output becomes an N*N array where each element of the original vector becomes 1 row of the array

Your function works correctly. How did you save it? Do you maybe have a different encrypt function that comes earlier in the search path? -- By the way, in your function you never initialize adjustedvec, meaning it gets expanded every loop iteration, which is inefficient.

Works for me too - https://drive.mathworks.com/sharing/7cf3919f-2a7c-4e7a-80e9-b5a43f95b978/so_78593958.mlx

I agree. The function is ok. A plaintxt=plaintxt(:); inside the function maly solve a possible NxN input, so far unknown.

1.- Problem from input, not from function
The quick answer is you input an NxN to double and therefore you obtain as output also an NxN matrix.
If you do
L1="abc def";
double(L1)

L1 = abc def
 =

    97    98    99    32   100   101   102

or
double(L1')
 =

    97
    98
    99
    32
   100
   101
   102

MATLAB returns the expected 1xN or Nx1  string.
But if you do
double(L1'*L1)

then
=
9409    9506    9603    3104    9700    9797    9894
9506    9604    9702    3136    9800    9898    9996
9603    9702    9801    3168    9900    9999   10098
3104    3136    3168    1024    3200    3232    3264
9700    9800    9900    3200   10000   10100   10200
9797    9898    9999    3232   10100   10201   10302
9894    9996   10098    3264   10200   10302   10404

You are only showing the function that you mention it works ok.
Please include in your question the input or a sample of the input as you call it in your main.
Also
2.-
in MATLAB for this particular case please consider not using a for loop :
% coding
pt='Normandie 10am'
k=3
ac = double(pt);
    if (ac+ k) > 90
        diff = (ac + k) - 90;
        aout= 64 + diff;
    else
        aout = ac + k;
    end

cout = char(aout)

% decoding
pt2=cout;
k2=-3
ac2 = double(pt2);
    if (ac2+ k2) > 90
        diff2 = (ac2 + k2) - 90;
        aout2 = 64 + diff2;
    else
        aout2= ac2+ k2;
    end

cout2 = char(aout2)

now it works ok
pt = Normandie 10am
k = 3
cout = Qrupdqglh#43dp
k2 = -3
cout2 = Normandie 10am

3.- Pull input to make sure
Also, if reviewing or modifying the input that causes NxN output not possible then try adding the following line inside the function
plaintext=plaintext(:);

this way you make sure that whatever size shows up as input, your function is only processing all elements one by one indian file.
Hope it helps.
Thanks for reading

That if statement does not do what you think it does. The code you posted does not do what OP’s code does. In MATLAB, if array is the same as if all(array(:)).

Let's avoid syntax discussions and let's keep eyes on the ball : the problem exposed in this question has to do with an unknown input to the supplied function, not obtaining a 1xN output, but NxN

So let's see if arm618 supplies the unknown input, that as explained in my answer, I suspect is the actual cause of the problem, not the function itself.

To Cris Luengo : input=input(:); is used in many built-in functions. Obviously for an if clause there's no need to pull whatever size to 1 x prod(size(input)) but to resize from whatever size the input shows up with, to 1xN.

I don’t know what you’re arguing here. What I’m saying is that the loop-less alternative your propose here doesn’t work. It takes one branch of the if/else statement for the whole array, it doesn’t take a different branch for each element as OP’s code does.

ok, I disagree with what you say about having to use a for loop. Let's wait for Arm618 to say something.

and this may be a long wait
